# jquery plugin callback to reset default option

Tags: javascript, jquery

my poor js drives me crazy. i used a jquery plugin called  raty, which is a star rating plugin

i used it like this way

```
 $('span.sessionRating').raty({starOff: 'images/star-off.png', starOn: 'images/star-on.png', click: sessionRate});

 function sessionRate (score, evt) {
    $(this).raty ({readOnly:true});
}
```

the problem is `$(this).raty ({readOnly:true})` will recreate the star rating again. so i am wondering how can we reset the option without recreating everything;

thanks. i have googled a lot, but found no answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/wbotelhos/raty):

```
$('div').raty('readOnly', boolean);      // Change the read-only state.
```

So you could try this:

```
function sessionRate (score, evt) {
    $(this).raty('readOnly', true);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Daniel, thanks, it worked. i didnt thought that is the way to set the option. thanks very much !

Comment: No worries. That's very common with the jQuery plugins, when initialized you pass an object with the options and after that you call different functions or change options passing a string with the name of the function/option.